# set where for foriegn table in laravel relation

Tags: php, laravel, relation

I have a table has many relation to other tables but it seperated with `entity` value please look at this :

i have this schema

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('cards', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('entity_id');
            $table->string('entity');
            $table->integer('qty')->nullable()->default('1');
        });
    }


    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tickets', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('summary');
            $table->integer('amount');
            $table->integer('stock')->default('0');
            $table->integer('discount')->default('0');
        });
    }

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->integer('title');
            $table->integer('amount');
            $table->integer('discount');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->integer('stock')->default('0');
        });
    }
```

and this relation in models

```
class Card extends Model 
{

    protected $table = 'cards';
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function ticket()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Ticket', 'entity_id');
    }

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Product', 'entity_id');
    }

}
```

i need to set `where entity = 'ticket'` before use `belongsTo` i mean is a table hase relation to many table base `entity_id` and i seperated it by `entity` column and base same vlue most have realation just.

Comment: you can use hasmanythrough. https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: thanks @codeformoney but it'snt my solotion. i need where statement for belongs to.

Comment: please tell me what `input` do you have and what `output` do you want

Answer (score 0):

You can do simply in your eloquent model file. do like this :

```
public function ticketWithCondition()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Ticket', 'entity_id')->where('entity' , 'ticket');
}

public function ticket()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Ticket', 'entity_id');
}
```

call like this :

```
// for show Card with EntityCondition
$comments = Card::find(123)->with('ticketWithCondition');

// for show comments without EntityCondition
$comments = Card::find(123)->with('ticket');
```

Comment: thanks. but the `entity` column is in card table not `ticket or order`